# Efficient way for computation of derivatives of $f(x) = \zeta(1-x) + 1/x $ at integer x?

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, divergent-series

***[This question is copied from [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323657), it didn't get answers so far]***

For some exercises with (divergent) [summation of the Stieltjes constants,see also MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202667) I'm trying a formula, which involves derivatives of the $\zeta()$ -function at negative integers; perhaps better formulated as  $$ f(x) = \zeta(1-x) + 1/x \qquad x \in \mathbb N $$ and then the scaled derivatives  $$ g(x,d) = x^d \cdot {f^{(d)}(x)\over d!} $$.

In Pari/GP there is a very nice procedure for the computation of $\zeta$ implemented, but I don't see anything for the derivatives except to implement numerical differentiation along the line ${f(x+\epsilon/2) - f(x-\epsilon/2)\over \epsilon}$ and so on, but which becomes inaccurate for higher derivatives.
For small *x* I can use the representation of the function $f(x)$ as a power series involving the Stieltjes-constants themselves, but a suitable computation is then possible only for a small range of *x*-values if I use only, say 100 or 200 terms of the power series.

Q: What would be a more efficient representation of $f(x)$ and/or $g(x)$ for the actual computation, where -say- *x* and *d* both can go up to 100 or 200 ? Note, that for high *c* (the index for the partial sums, see below) there is the significant effect , that either (x is small and d is high) or converse, such that *d+x* in the terms of one partial sum is constant.

---

More context: what I'm finally after is to be able to explore the partial sums and its single terms in
$$ S \underset{\mathfrak E}{=} \lim_{c\to \infty} S(c) = \sum_{k=0}^{c} (-1)^k g( c+1-k ,k) $$ which should be a representation for the (divergent) sum of the Stieltjes constants, taken by some *"Eulerian"* summation procedure $\mathfrak E$  (see an [earlier post here on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58083)).

Comment: this earlier post might be relevant:

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/120232/pair-correlation-for-the-riemann-zeros-and-zeta-primes-zetas-prime

Comment: @Carlo - thank you very much; I'll take a deeper look at it later...

Comment: Maybe related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340718/references-to-integrals-of-the-form-int-01-left-frac1-log-x-frac

Answer (score 2):

The Euler-Maclaurin formula works quite well.

I have implemented simultaneous computation of $(\zeta(s,a), \zeta'(s,a) \ldots, \zeta^{(n)}(s,a))$ for arbitrary $s, a \in \mathbb{C}$, with the option to subtract $1/(s-1)$ to remove the singularity at $s = 1$, in my library for ball arithmetic [Arb](http://fredrikj.net/arb/). All the derivatives are computed with rigorous error bounds (as currently described on [this page](http://fredrikj.net/arb/fmpcb.html)).

As a benchmark, computing the first 1000 Stieltjes constants to 1000 accurate digits (using 1500 digits of precision to give $\gamma_0$ accurate to 1500 digits and $\gamma_{1000}$ accurate to 1000 digits) takes 14 seconds, and computing the first 5000 Stieltjes constants to 5000 digits takes 40 minutes.

Comment: Hi Fredrik, did you mean to apply the Euler-Maclaurin formula directly at the Stieltjes-numbers? 

Comment: Yes (if I understand your question directly), the Euler-Maclaurin formula works directly for zeta at any integer, and gives you the Stieltjes constants at $s = 1$ after just removing the singular $1/(s-1)$ term.

Comment: Ah, so I see, there was possibly a misunderstanding. I have the first 500 Stieltjes constants to 1000 digits by a nice, small procedure. What I was trying to do, was to give a sense to the sum-of-all-Stieltjes numbers, by some summation-procedure. That procedure requires to use the derivatives of the zetas in a certain manner in finite sums as written above. That finite sums, having more and more terms according to the increasing parameter *c*, approximate something like 0.4990749...xyz , but convergence is slow and needs many of the zeta's derivatives...